# Connecting remotely to database with FQDN identified user (instead of IP)

Tags: java, mysql, connection, ip, fqdn

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database remotely, from a machine called `pc.domain.com` to a server called `remotehost.domain.com`

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://remotehost:3306", "user", "pass");
```

On the remote server I have the user `'user'@'pc.domain.com'` (with appropriate permissions), but when I try to connect the following error occurs:

```
Host '128.0.200.82' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I don't know if such validation is server or client side, although it makes more sense to be server sided. How can I force it to use the FQDN instead of the IP address to identify the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem with the reverse lookup on my DNS.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you fixed the problem. I am facing an issue with remote mysql connection from windows client to mysql server running on Linux host. Granting permission to Windows IP works but it doesnt work with frequently qualified domain name of windows server. Since I have both these servers on AWS, IP is not reliable to use and I need to move it to FQDN.

Comment: Check your DNS server, aside from the usual `A` record pointing from the FQDN to the IP address of the mysql server, it must have a reverse lookup pointing from the IP address of the mysql server to the FQDN. Since you're using AWS, I never used it, but I assume it's DNS system must have this IP -> FQDN -> IP relation established by some automatic process, which may be misconfigured or failing, better look for in AWS docs.

Comment: Not sure about reverse dns lookup.
Howerver, in remote mysql server, we can grant access with wildcard '<USER>'@'%' which means user from any host can access it. 
Will it have any security concern on production. Can we avoid it in AWS by specifying security group with CidrIp to allow specific hosts.


CREATE USER '<USER>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY <PWD>;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <DB>.* TO '<USER>'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: I'm not sure how Cidrlp works since I never used it, that question will be better answered in their documentation, or by someone who faced such issue.

Comment: How to verify if the issue is with mysql server or AWS? As I can connect to mysql server if we grant access to 'Client IP' inside mysql server. But when granting access with client fqdn - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <DB>.* TO '<USER>'@'client.example.com' WITH GRANT OPTION;` , getting error at client side -- [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Host '<Client IP>' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server (1130) (SQLDriverConnect)

Comment: That's because your mysql server doesn't know which FQDN corresponds to that IP, which means it can't find a reverse PTR for that IP. Could be due to a configuration on the mysql server, for instance the host OS doesn't have a DNS server properly configured, or could be due to the DNS server not actually having the correspondent reverse PTR. You can check [here](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/changing-dns-settings-on-linux/) to see if it's on the mysql host side, and if it's on the DNS server side the solution will be specific to whathever server you're using.